# Артефакты изображения после обработки

Tags: java, изображения, обработка-изображений, bufferedimage, артефакты

Обрабатывается изображение.
Сначала берётся исходное изображение. Я добавляю к каждому саб-пикселю шум.

После восстанавливаю от шума, вычитанием из саб-пикселя шума.
Но что то происходит не так.

До обработки изображения оно выглядит нормально :
[image: Исходное изображение]

После обработки появляются артефакты в некоторых засвеченных местах.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще не понимаю, куда и как думать, в каком направлении. До этого была похожая проблема, но решалась сменой формата изображения с JPG на PNG.
В формате BMP проблема остаётся такой же.

**Код обработки изображения:**

```
for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < DEPTH; z++) {
                Color cryptColor = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
                img.setRGB(x, y, new Color(
                        overflowControl(cryptColor.getBlue(), reconstructedNoise[x][y][2], OPERATION_MINUS),
                        overflowControl(cryptColor.getRed(), reconstructedNoise[x][y][0], OPERATION_MINUS),
                        overflowControl(cryptColor.getGreen(), reconstructedNoise[x][y][1], OPERATION_MINUS)
                ).getRGB());
            }
        }
    }
```

**Код вызываемого метода :**

```
private static final int HIGH = 255;

private int overflowControl(int color, int noiseNumber, int operation) {
        switch (operation) {
            case OPERATION_PLUS: {
                if (color + noiseNumber > HIGH) {
                    return color + noiseNumber - HIGH;
                }
                return color + noiseNumber;
            }
            case OPERATION_MINUS: {
                if (color - noiseNumber < 0) {
                    return HIGH + (color - noiseNumber);
                }
                return color - noiseNumber;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

**P.S.** Вы можете подумать, что проблема в несоответствии порядка извлечения и установки цветов. Возможно вы правы, но по факту [так и задумано] цвета остаются идентичными, кроме как некоторых участков.

Comment: Обратите внимание, артефакты только на белом цвете(освещении), возможно что-то ещё в файлах, в зависимости от того как они генерируются. Если не секрет, зачем Вам эта схема?

Comment: @artemgh просто люблю баловаться с изображениями. Сейчас на стадии "испортить изображение и вернуть всё, как было". Но эта проблема заставила меня понять, что ещё мне предстоит изучить.

Comment: Понял, в таком случае удачи)

Comment: А, я понял что не так, белый это же и есть 255, там дальше не куда прибавлять

Comment: @artemgh так у меня ведь для этого есть метод overflowControl, который в случае превышения максимального значения при сложении кода цвета с шумом присваивает разницу. 
Например значение цвета 62. Значение шума 240. 240+62=302. 302>255 => 302-255=47.
После для восстановления используем то же число шума.
47 - 240 = -193. 193 < 0 => 255 + (-193) = 62
Вот по такой схеме всё работает.

Comment: Точно, вижу *Не хватает*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось всё математическим анализом того, что я написал.
Анализом функции нескольких переменных, а конкретно моей функции контроля переполнения числа, отвечающего за яркость сабпикселя - Z = f(X,Y), где X - значение цвета, а Y - значение шума на области определения X[0; 255], Y[0;255], Z[0;255].

Грубо говоря все ошибки были в расчётах метода **overflowControl**

При этом сначала возникали артефакты на ярких местах, то есть проблема была в неправильной коррекции числа на высоких яркостях.
После устранения точек прерывания функции возникла другая проблема..
После начали возникать артефакты на тёмных областях.
После устранения точек прерывания функции на низких яркостях всё прошло успешно.

**Вот итоговый код:**

```
private int overflowControl(int color, int noiseNumber, int operation) {
    switch (operation) {
        case OPERATION_PLUS: {
            if (color + noiseNumber > HIGH) {
                if(color == HIGH && noiseNumber != LOW) {
                    return noiseNumber - 1;
                }
                return color + noiseNumber - HIGH - 1;
            }
            return color + noiseNumber;
        }
        case OPERATION_MINUS: {
            if (color - noiseNumber < LOW) {
                if (color - noiseNumber == -1) {
                    return HIGH;
                }
                return HIGH + (color - noiseNumber) + 1;
            }
            return color - noiseNumber;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("-1 => error overflowControl");
    return -1;
}
```